# iOS custom keyboard with math symbols

Tags: ios

In my app I have some UITextViews that can be edited. Since the app is a maths application, I would like to add to the normal iOS keyboard some sort of pad, or tab where the user can pick certain math symbols that are not present in the normal iOS keyboard, for example square roots, functions, fractions.

Is this possible? Is there any third party sdk which does this?

Comment: Ok, I had already seen this, as others, but none give you the option for maths symbles

Comment: Look at the source code of the first answer. It's up to you which text and image you set for the keyboard buttons.

Comment: I didn't notice, works fine now, thanks